# Force fsck check after reboot with single command

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, fsck

I'm looking for systemd's equivalent to the `shutdown -F` command. 
I know that I can force fsck by adding `fsck.mode=force` to kernel options or tweak mount count for disks.
I have tried `touch /forcefsck` but it doesn't work with latest systemd versions.

Comment: According to archwiki, `fsck.mode=force` is indeed your only option https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fsck#Forcing_the_check

Answer (score 3):

When I want to force fsck, I just use the following command:

```
# tune2fs -C 50 /dev/sda2
```

It simply sets the mount counter to 50, but I also have set:

```
# tune2fs -l
...
Mount count:              18
Maximum mount count:      20
```

So as you can see, when I set 50 in mount count, kernel thinks it should fsck the partition.

This solution works always, no matter what you use sysvinit/systemd or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

systemd's `shutdown -F` equivalent is `systemctl poweroff`. I haven't figured out the relation with fsck.
However, AFAIK, you can not force fsck using systemd, because fsck is executed *before* systemd starts.

Comment: If you add -F flag to shutdown command it will force fsck execution after reboot: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shutdown

Comment: It just passes fsck.mode=force to the kernel. With systemd I guess you can't AFAIK.

Comment: systemd is init, i.e. the very first program executed, so fsck necessarily takes place after systemd is run.