# archlinux check disks on boot

Tags: arch-linux, ext4, fsck

How can I check and mark bad blocks on Linux startup? There are a number of options available and most of them require accessing hardware and running live CD's. But I would like to avoid and perform everything using command line without going to the server room and talking to admins who have the keys.

I have ArchLinux with `/` on `ext4fs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your init scripts support it, you can add `-c -c` to `/fsckoptions` (then create `/forcefsck` and reboot). Unfortunately, this feature isn't available everywhere. You probably have to reboot to a LiveCD/LiveUSB instead.

[Perform Bad Blocks Scan on Root Partition in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/215820/perform-bad-blocks-scan-on-root-partition-in-linux)

Comment: On Arch you still can force fsck check with kernel parameters `fsck.mode=force`. May be related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106892/force-fsck-check-after-reboot-with-single-command

Comment: yes, i've forced fsck using manual from ArchLinux. Next challenge is to run badblocks, but seems that i have to go to server room and use LiveCD. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure if that works, but you could go into single user mode, remount / readonly, and then run badblocks.