# reboot with one-time kernel parameters

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, systemd, grub2, kernel-parameters

Is there a possibility to pass a (set of additional) kernel boot parameters to be applied at the *next* (re)boot, and *only* at that boot?

- I know that i could just interrupt `grub` and manually pass the boot parameters. This is **not** what i want (think: multiple remote computers that need to be booted with a given kernel option; needing to be physically present during the initial boot phase is a logistical nightmare)
- I know that i could modify `/etc/default/grub` and pass the appropriate `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. or just edit `/etc/grub/grub.cfg` manually).
  However, i would like to set the parameters only for a *single* boot and the values in `/etc/grub/grub.cfg` will be persistent.
- I also would like to boot the "currently active" kernel, so having a persistent entry in my `grub.cfg` with the kernel-parameter set, would require to alway be automatically updated when a new kernel is installed.

#### Background

Actually i'm looking for a simple way to force a filesystem check on (next) reboot.
My filesystems are all journalled, so they have a `max_mount_count=-1`.
Since (almost) all of my systems use `systemd` these days, the good olde tricks like `touch /forcefsck` won't work, and instead i *must* pass `fsck.mode=force` to the kernel options.

I'm aware of [Force fsck check after reboot with single command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106892), though this doesn't help much.

The target systems run Debian/jessie with linux-3.16, if that matters (though I would prefer a general solution)

Comment: check out `kexec` ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this. The workaround is to make a "permanent" change to the kernel parameters and after the next boot, undo the the change.

Answer (score 0):

Several bootloaders implement the so-called *boot-once* support:

- for GRUB, you can use [grub-reboot N](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574295/how-can-i-get-grub2-to-boot-a-different-option-only-on-the-next-boot),
- for the Syslinux family the [--once "cmd"](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=EXTLINUX) option.

Comment: For systemd-boot, use `systemctl reboot _name_`, where `_name_` is the name of a boot entry that will be selected at next boot and only the next boot. Caveats: this requires a UEFI system (the selected entry is stored in an EFI variable), and kernel version 4.7 or later compiled with `EFI_BOOTLOADER_CONTROL`. See [efibc: Add EFI Bootloader Control module](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=06f7d4a1618dbb086e738c93cd1ef416ab01027d) and [systemd-boot](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/systemd-boot/).

Comment: this allows me to pre-select a boot-entry, which is not necessarily the same as adding a kernel-option. in any case, for this to properly work, i would need a way to have a (persistently numbered) entry of the *currently active* kernel with the `fsck.mode=force`. the catch is to make sure, that there is an entry for the current kernel...

Comment: Syslinux lets you pass a one-time command line, which needn't correspond to any persistent boot entry. Modern Syslinux lets you script bootloader operation in [Lua](http://lua.org), even. For example, you can scan your boot partition for the latest kernel on the fly, without ever modifying the configuration. Or implement some analogue of `/forcefsck`.